# What is Micro ORM?

Tags: hibernate, orm

Why a Object Relational Mapping (ORM) framework is called a Micro ORM but not full featured ORM? Which features and/or non-existent features makes an ORM framework, a Micro ORM?

I derived following features from my knowledge of Hibernate, NHibernate, Entity Framework. But I would like to learn more about this. A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=what%20is%20micro%20orm) gives a lot of library/framework results but no satisfactory definition of Micro ORM in TOP results.

- Cache
- Second Level Cache
- Inheritance Mapping
- Query Language (HQL, JPAQL etc)
- Different Mapping Strategies

  - One class per table
  - ...
- Many-to-One, one-to-one, Many-to-Many mappings
- ...

Is following libraries considered as Micro ORM? why / why not?

- [Data Access Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649538.aspx) in .NET
- [ibatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the goal of an Micro ORM is to ease implementation and also to possibly improve performance.  I've seen people write custom Micro ORMs that used a DataReader behind the scenes, to provide a fast/readonly ORM.

I'm not sure about the two you mentioned, but I do know that  [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) and [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) are good examples of Micro ORMs

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a Micro ORM does not support the following:

- LINQ queries or any custom query language
- Lazy Loading
- Proxying
- Caching

They tend to be simple and easy to use.

Another alternative to the ones Dan listed is [MicroLite](http://microliteorm.wordpress.com) (disclaimer: I am the author of it).